# Does Italian language have 'phrasal verbs'?

Tags: grammar, english-comparison

Phrasal verbs:

> A phrasal verb consists of a verb and a preposition or adverb that modifies or changes the meaning; 'give up' is a phrasal verb that means 'stop doing' something, which is very different from 'give'. The word or words that modify a verb in this manner can also go under the name particle. Examples:

- ask someone out: invite on a date.
- break down: stop functioning (vehicle, machine)
- do away with something:   discard.

If not,why?

Answer (score 14):

In Italian they are called "[verbi sintagmatici](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-sintagmatici_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/)". Yes, they do exist in Italian, read the link for lots of examples. They are "verbi [polirematici](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-polirematiche_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/)", i.e. composed of more than one word in such a way that the meaning cannot be obtained from its components.

Some sources:

> Per intenderci subito, definirò i VS come sintagmi formati da una testa verbale e da un complemento costituito da una “particella” (originariamente un avverbio), uniti da una coesione sintattica di grado elevato al punto che non si può commutare il VS intero con una sola delle sue parti.
>
> Raffaele Simone, Esistono verbi sintagmatici in italiano?

and

> Benché segnalati sporadicamente (De Mauro 1963: 385-386 parla, per es., di «particelle locative aggiunte al verbo, in posizione accentata»), i verbi sintagmatici sono oggetto di studi a sé solo a partire dai contributi di Schwarze (1985) e specialmente di Simone (1997; lavori recenti in Cini 2008a). Lo stesso termine *verbo sintagmatico* (ormai affermatosi a scapito di soluzioni precedenti, come *verbo complesso*, *verbo composto*, *verbo perifrastico* o *verbo analitico*) è quello proposto da Simone, sul modello dell'inglese *phrasal verb*.
>
> Hanne Jansen, [Verbi Sintagmatici](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-sintagmatici_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/), Enciclopedia dell'Italiano (2011)

and

> Il crescente interesse per i verbi a particella in Italiano (d'ora in poi V+Part) come *buttare giù*, *tirare su*, *fare fuori* – definiti a partire da Simone (1997) ― **verbi sintagmatici** – ha visto coinvolti negli ultimi decenni una pluralità di linguisti e studiosi i quali, nonostante la diversa prospettiva adottata, concordano nel riconoscere che i *phrasal verbs* esistono nella lingua italiana parlata e che la loro pervasività e produttività non può più essere ignorata (Antelmi, 2002; Iacobini, 2007; Jansen, 2004).
>
> Da [Atti del congresso internazionale sulla comunicazione parlata
> (Napoli, 23-25 febbraio 2009)](http://opar.unior.it/336/1/La_comunicazione_parlata_3_-_vol._I.pdf)

Comment: Yes, but they are not actually phrasal verbs in the way described above. The adverb or preposition added don't actually change the meaning of the verb as in the case of the English language.

Comment: That is highly controversial. Italian linguists are convinced that there is no real difference between English "phrasal verbs" and Italian "verbi sintagmatici".

Comment: @Josh61: some do: *fare* (=to do) is clearly different from *fare fuori* (=to kill). *Mettere* (=to put) e *mettere sotto* (=to run over). *Dare* (=to give) e *dare addosso* (=pester, rage against someone).

Comment: @nico And *fare senso* (to be disgusted) to link with [an other question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/avere-senso-vs-fare-senso).